# Regex for unicode words with hyphens, numbers or other real world signs

Tags: regex, string, unicode

I've tried a bunch of regex codes for parsing words, and even though I can create a code for parsing them right, I find it difficult to convert it to regex. I'm not satisfied with my code, because it relies on a lot of 'ifs' and manual replacements.

Here is my test case:

> String phrase = "O mapa-múndi encontra-se com J.A.Adams -- autor
>   'lúdico' -- e custa 0,62% zenny's, o equivalente a R$452,10 (ou
>   $200).";

Here is my desired output:

> String words[] = new String[]{"O", "mapa-múndi", "encontra-se", "com",
>   "J.A.Adams", "autor", "lúdico", "e", "custa", "0,62%", "zenny's", "o",
>   "equivalente", "a", "R$452,10", "ou", "$200"};

I've tried the "([^\p{L}\p{N}-'’]|$|^)+", but it starts with an empty string and removes the dots from names (J.A.Adams) and commas from numbers, along with other problems.

Some rules:

- Unicode caracters (e.g. 'lúdico');
- Remove ' or " or - in the beginning or end of words;
- Keep ' or - or $ or . or , in the middle of words or numbers (e.g. J.A.Adams, mapa-múndi, encontra-se, 0,62, zenny's, R$452,10.
- Remove (or ignore) other dashes, parenthesis, commas, punctuation (? or !).

Comment: I'd split the string on spaces then sanitize each word (ie. remove the ones that contain only invalid characters).

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm working with Java, but any language will do, because I can easily adapt the RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of something better, you might want to try (working along your example):

1. Get the actual phrase `O mapa-múndi encontra-se com J.A.Adams -- autor 'lúdico' -- e custa 0,62% zenny's, o equivalente a R$452,10 (ou $200).`
2. RegEx search for `((?<=^| )[- '",(.!?]+)|([-'",).!?]+(?= |$))` and replace with nothing.

   - Use `((?<=^| )[- '",(.!?]+)|([-'",)!?]+(?= ))|([-'",).!?]+(?=$))` instead, if you need to preserve dots preceeding the blanks in, e.g., `J. R. Ewing` or the one trailing `e.g.`or `i.e.` This will, of course not work any longer, when the *String phrase* to start with may hold more than a single sentence ending in a full stop (of which all but the last one would no longer be removed).
   - Either one applies two/three subpatterns, of which the first one `((?<=^| )[- '",(.!?]+)` combines a lookbehind for the "start of the string" or a blank `(?<=^| )` with a character class `[- '",(.!?]`, which should be matched at least once `+`. The other one(s) do(es) similarly - but with a lookforward.
3. RegEx search for `((?<=^| )[^ ]+?(?= |$))` and replace with `"\1",`.

   - The same positive lookbehind followed by a non-greedy "anything but a blank" `[^ ]+?` and a lookforward for a blank or the "end of the line" `(?= |$))`.
   - To return, e.g., `J.R. Ewing` as a token but not `e.g. Ewing` with a generic solution, one might have a chance as long as the pre-blank group is (all) lower case (or follows some other rule(s), which can be expressed with a regex). For a start, I'd just add the to be kept together ones to the start of the search expression like `((J.R. Ewing)|(J. ?A. Adams)|((?<=^| )[-\w0-9'$.,%]+?(?= |$)))`, that is, each token between parentheses `()` and followed by a pipe character. The question mark in `J. ?A. Adams` will help to catch both of `J.A. Adams` and `J.A. Adams`. (Placing these tokens at the end of the search string will render them useless for the intended purpose.)
   - The candidates for the latter might be retrieved with something along `(([A-Z]\. ?)+ [A-Z][a-z]+)` run against the whole corpus during the set up. (Would need to do it this way in order to be able to add it to the regex in one go rather than for each line individually.)
4. Strip away the trailing comma.
5. Surround the result by `String words[] = new String[]{` and `};`

Tested with TextWrangler 4.5.11, which handles Unicode automatically. Thus can't test

- RegEx search for `((?<=^| )[-\p{L}\p{N}'$.,%]+?(?= |$))` and replace with `"\1",`.
- The closest I did get, is a search for `((?<=^| )[-\w0-9'$.,%]+?(?= |$))`.

(Both of which do include the `%`, which seems to be missing from the spelled out requirements.)

(Please remember, to match a hyphen with a character class, that hyphen needs to go first in the class like `[-ab89]` - otherwise it will denote the range between the characters immediately next to it.)

Comment: Thanks! The first RegEx replace worked for my test cases. I've just added some extra chars (like : and ;) and then added a split on "\\s+" (Java language). Would you mind explaining it further for other viewers?

Comment: Also, there is one minor thing: "J.R.R.Tolkien" is parsed correctly, but if I got a space after, like "J.R.R. Tolkien" or "a.c." or "i.e.", then the last '.' is removed. What would you suggest to solve this, i.e., splitting into "J.R.R.", "Tolkien", "a.c." and "i.e."?

Comment: @IsaacDuhor Tuned it based on your feedback and added asked for explanations. A different approach to the blanks in, e.g., "J.R.R. Tolkien" would be, to drop the blank in a pre-processing step for the whole corpus, and to add it back in after all suggested above work is done. Whichever makes more sense does largely depend on the specifics of your overall task(s) - such as whether this is a one time only job, the number of patterns to take care of, etc. - Feel free to add more detail if and as you see fit.